# How to change clip speed in Lightworks 14

Tags: lightworks

The new interface for Lightworks 14 has reorganized the control for clip speed to somewhere else.  You used to click the Advanced button at the bottom right of the timeline to make the speed controls pop up, but the Advanced button appears to no longer exist.  How can I change the speed of a section of video in the timeline?

Answer (score 2):

Ah!  Okay, so apparently you now right-click on the clip and select "Speed.." from the context menu.  The location of the mouse pointer when you right-click doesn't seem to matter.  Not sure if the location of the current playback point still determines the stable point during the speed change.